# Passing recordset into array causes UBound(array) to be 1 not the correct number

Tags: excel, multidimensional-array, vba

I preform a query and save the recordset to an array so I can further manipulate the results. When I try to find the size of the array UBound gives me 1 as an answer, but I know that the size is 107. Is there another way to find the size of an array?

The array is a 2d array and the recordset assigns it (0,1) from 0 to 106. I use GetRows to copy the recordset to the array.

```
    array = recordset.GetRows
```

Comment: Could you share you code please on how you're assigning the recordset to an array? Also is it a 2D array?

Comment: Gareth, I added some more information to make my question more clear.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `ADODB` I generally use the following to assign a recordset to an array like so:

```
Option Explicit

Private Const gcConn As String = "Your connection string"

Public Function fGetData() As Variant()

Dim oDB As ADODB.Connection: Set oDB = New ADODB.Connection
Dim oCM As ADODB.Command: Set oCM = New ADODB.Command
Dim oRS As ADODB.Recordset

On Error GoTo Err:

oDB.Open gcConn

With oCM
    .ActiveConnection = oDB
    .CommandType = adCmdText
    .CommandText = "Your SQL"
    Set oRS = .Execute
End With

If Not oRS.BOF And Not oRS.EOF Then
    fGetData = oRS.GetRows()
Else
    Erase fGetData
End If

oRS.Close
Set oRS = Nothing
oDB.Close
Set oDB = Nothing

Exit Function

Err:
    'Some error handling here

End Function
```

From there you can assign this to a variant variable and loop through the results like so:

```
Public Sub fDoSomething()

Dim varList As Variant
Dim i As Long, j As Long

varList = fGetData

For i = LBound(varList, 2) To UBound(varList, 2)
    For j = LBound(varList, 1) To UBound(varList, 1)
        MsgBox varList(j, i)
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

I always check first though before using the array to make sure that there is records in there and that it wasn't erased (as there was no records returned).

Comment: I've been googling how to assign recordset to a variable and loop through it, how to copy a recordset to a variant and iterate, how to loop through getrows and how to loop though recordset after it has closed - wasnt getting much luck but this was the answer to what I was trying to find out so massive thanks